# Cannot install with wubi

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, wubi

Apologies if this has been posted before, but I need some help installing 12.04 alongside windows.

I downloaded the ISO (64 bit) then created a bootable cd with it.  Then I downloaded wubi. I proceeded to select the size of the partition (20GB) and set my username and password.

The installation begins, and asks me to reboot after a while. Upon reboot, the splash page comes up and the installation continues, completes and reboots. I then get the following error:

```
No wubildr; prefix not found
```

At that point I'm left in what looks like a terminal or command prompt.

How can I make the install work?

Comment: That message `no wubildr; prefix not found` can be ignored (happens on all wubi installs). Are there any other messages? Are you left at a grub prompt? (Describe the screen). Also more information about your computer specs and drive (raid, partition type) would help.

Comment: Yes, as @bcbc said, it's normal and can be ignored, wait for 2-3 minutes and ubuntu will continue installing

Answer (score 1):

reinstall WUBI by this typing this on command prompt,   **D:\wubi.exe --force-wubi**
(D:\ is where your ubuntu cd is)

and if you are using win 7, run WUBI with administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Wubi and the .iso image is all on the hard drive of your computer. If it's on an external drive or storage it maybe will prompt you errors. Second, if you have installed Wubi previously, I suggest to uninstall it and delete files related with Wubi, as I said, move Wubi and the .iso image to the computer's hard drive (my documents, desktop, whatever) and run it from there. If this does not help you, I agree with @mahboobeAlam ... just follow the instructions on ubuntu.com of how to make a live cd or a live usb, edit bios for starting from the usb/cd and follow the instructions. You can make the partition before installing ubuntu but I would recommend not to do it and make that partition while installing Ubuntu. It's easy and it makes the dirty work for you. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that wubi is not supported in Ubuntu 12.04.. You will have to install it from live system (boot the cd and install ubuntu alongside Windows). The best ways is that you make an empty partition with a minimum size of 15 GB on your Hard Disk and then run the ubuntu live system and run install, then select that empty partition for installation.

Comment: Wubi is still supported in 12.04. A normal install is always better, but Wubi is still available for people who want to try out Ubuntu without repartitioning.